# Is there a way to highlight a set of custom keywords in ace editor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ace-editor

I'm trying to highlight a couple of keywords that are present in this.$rules . However I'm not able to get the final output . Can you please tell me what I'm missing here?

This is what I have tried inside an Angular component

Please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-itijpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I would appreciate your help . Thanks in advance !